# Adobe PDF Test Toolkit Installation problems with QTP

Tags: pdf, qtp

I'm using QTP 9.1 and Reader 9.

I downloaded the Adobe PDF Test Toolkit from [HERE](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Adobe-PDF-Test-Toolkit-Download-146912.html) and went through the following steps from the included installation instructions:

1. Extract the zip file into any location (I used C:\PDFTT)
2. Copy AcroQTP.exe, Automation.api and regPDFTestToolkit.bat to the
   folder [Adobe Reader Install folder]\plug_ins
3. Run regPDFTestToolkit.bat (which ran without error).

After going through these steps, the add-in should appear in QTP's add-in page, but it does not.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [requirement list](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/Adobe-PDF-Test-Toolkit.shtml), it looks like you will have to upgrade from QTP 9.1.

**Requirements:**

- Client software:
- Adobe Acrobat 9.2 or
- Adobe Reader 9.2
- HP Quick Test Pro ***9.5 or 10.0***, and updates
- Flex Builder 3.0.2 (optional)
- Flex QTP Plugin (optional)
- Server software:
- LiveCycle Server 8.2 or later (optional)
- Browser:

  - Internet Explorer 6 or later (XP) or
  - Internet Explorer 7 or later (Vista)

Answer (score 0):

Do a full installation of adobe acrobat reader ( Not Adobe Reader ).I had problems trying to do it with adobe reader alone. The add-in should appear after a full installation of the same.
Best of luck.